# SimpleDateFormat parse throws exception

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I have the following variable declaring format of `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
private static SimpleDateFormat  dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
```

When I try to parse following string with above format I get Unparsable date exception :

`newDate = dateFormat.parse("Mon Mar 24 16:49:31 UTC 2013")`;

What am I doing wrong? Any idea? It is strange that above line works in emulator, but not on phone.

Comment: Your date staring works for me. Are you sure that you copied *exact* string here? Your last character is not a correct semicolon, so I am afraid that there are other wrong (probably invisible) character in your example.

Comment: I don't see any special character. It is strange at it seems it works in emulator.